# Passing variable with POST from one page to another and print data in the previous one

Tags: php, json, post

I have 2 files: **basic.php** and **pptimeline.php**. The first holds the interface the second one is the file that gets the data from database and it is supposed to mimic a json file since I am using this on it: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

I have a combo box that displays numbers of process from a database and then displays it in timeline. I managed to pass the `$nprocesso` from basic.php to pptimeline.php and print it there. The thing is I want to pass `$nprocesso` to pptimeline.php, run the database's queries and then print the data in the basic.php, but I don't know how to do it since the form action leaves me stuck in the pptimeline.php page with the printed text in json format.

I hope I made myself clear.

**basic.php**

```
<form action="json/pptimeline.php" method="POST" >
<label for="Process"> NProcess : </label>
  <select id="cproc" name="NProc"     onchange="document.getElementById('nprocesso').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
  <?php
foreach ($products as $res3)
    {
        echo "<option value='".$res3["PROCESSO"]."'>".$res3["PROCESSO"]."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="nprocesso" id="nprocesso" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>
</form>

 <?php
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $nprocValue = $_POST['Proc'];
    $nproc = $_POST['nprocesso']; // get the selected text
}
?>
```

pptimeline.php

```
if (isset ($_REQUEST['nprocesso'])) {
$nprocesso = $_REQUEST['nprocesso'];
echo $nprocesso;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to use add header('Location: $new_url'); to redirect your pptimeline.php back to basic.php:

```
if (isset ($_REQUEST['nprocesso'])) {
    $nprocesso = $_REQUEST['nprocesso'];
    echo $nprocesso;
    header('Location: basic.php?v=$nprocesso'); 
}
```

And in basic.php add the following at the end:

```
if (isset($_GET['v']))
{
    echo $_GET['v']; 
}
```

**MOREOVER**

The solution provided above does the trick, but is far from the optimal way.

What you are looking for is making AJAX requests from basic.php to pptimeline.php and getting the results back to display on basic.php.

There is too much to cover, and code to change to tell you exactly how to do it. But I'll try to summarise:

1. Include [Jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js) in basic.php
2. Remove `<form></form>` surrounding your `<select></select>`, instead add an event handler to [click events](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
3. In the click handler, get the value selected by the user
4. Make a [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) inside the click handler and send (via POST) the value

In pptimeline.php:

1. `if (isset ($_POST['v']))` instead of $_REQUEST[]
2. remove the header() function, instead just echo the data you want to be sent back to the basic.php.
3. Don't forget to keep `header('Content-Type: application/json')` if you want the data in JSON

A AJAX post skeleton:

```
    $("#form1").on('click', function(){

    // get the selected value from <select>
    //var value = ....
    $.ajax()
    {
        url: "pptimeline.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"v" : value}
        success: function(response) {
            // some code to neatly display the results 
        }, 
        error: function(x,y,z){
            alert("an error occured"); 
        }
    });
```

## Detailed Code

**basic.php**

I replaced the option values in the `<select></select>` with an indexed value for simplicity.

```
    <label for="Process"> NProcess : </label>
    <select id="cproc" name="NProc"     onchange="document.getElementById('nprocesso').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
        <?php
        $i = 0; 
        for ($i=0; $i < 4;$i)
        {
            echo "<option value='$i'>". $i ."</option>";
            $i++; 

        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <button id="search-button"> Search-1 </button>

    <table border="1px" id="processes-table">
        <tr>
            <th> id</th>    
            <th> title</th>
            <th> description</th>
            <th> focus_date</th>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>


<script> 
    $("#cproc").on('change', function(){

        var v1 = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "pptimeline.php", 
            type: "POST", 
            data: {'value' : v1}, 
            success: function(response){
                var array = JSON.parse(response); 
                var _id = array['id']; 
                var _title = array['title']; 
                var _descr = array['description']; 
                var _focus_date = array['focus_date']; 

                var string = '<tr> <td>' + _id + ' </td> <td>'+ _title +' </td><td>'+_descr + '</td><td>' + _focus_date + '</td> </tr>'; 
                $('#processes-table tr:last').after(string);

            }, 
            error: function(x,y,z){
                alert("error"); 
            }
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

**pptimeline.php**
<?php

```
if (isset ($_POST['value'])) {
    $infotimeline = array(); 

    /*
     * REPLACE this with Database fetching/querying  
     */ 
    $infotimeline['id'] = 322; 
    $infotimeline['title'] = "the lion king";
    $infotimeline['description'] = "good movie";
    $infotimeline['focus_date'] = 1990; 

    $data = json_encode($infotimeline); 
    echo $data; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry if being dumb or something but I am very new to this .I have been trying to do what you said but i'm not quite there yet, since I don't know what to put in the `success:` and what you mean abotu echo the data. These are my files in images [basic.php](http://gyazo.com/60fff08d29854ba0a9bbcd5c1431e27f)  and [pptimeline1](http://gyazo.com/f413d2d3eb5bd6a9da1b5aba1c87a4f4) [pptimeline2](http://gyazo.com/4d7a61a26cad2b45d7936676287916bf) [pptimeline3](http://gyazo.com/491f56569044326f92b210e3bc264964)

Comment: In pptimeline1.php, put all of the code located after the if-block inside of it.
Then after having all the data in $infotimeline, 
$str = json_encode($infotimeline); 
echo $str;

And in basic.php, you need to parse the JSON string that you just received and make an array from it, I think you use JSON.parse(response). At this point, you have the array in basic.php. At this point, it is up to you how you want to display the data. One way would be to create a <table></table> and then put in there

Comment: I put inside the `success:` the code that calls the timeline as you can see in inside the green box and the green arrow is where I call my file - [basic.php2](http://gyazo.com/61f383824242a5264535eb94db73c932). I tried to do what you said in pptimeline.php but something is wrong in the `$_POST` part [pptimeline4](http://gyazo.com/b70e83ee139670945ccb66ff791a44f1). This is where the data is supposed to appear in the basic.php file - [basic.php3](http://gyazo.com/78c193534bb4934b13fdbcacc7c97aae)

Comment: I'm sorry but I answered your original question, I cannot do the whole project for you. Please mark the above answer as correct.

Comment: I would upvote but it says I need 15 reputation. You did answered my questions and helped me a lot, so I'm thankful for that. I don't want you to do the project for me, I wanna learn that is why I asked for guidance.